# Xcode 6 Storyboard Size Classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

there´s the new function called size classes to design once for every device. So i designed my Views in Compact Width and Regular Height, to support all iPhones in Portrait mode.

[image]

But what if i want to have one thing different on 3.5 inch devices?! How can i do that?I already tried to change the size class, but there´s no class especially for 3.5 inch devices...

Comment: Did you try compact height? or  use AnyHeight with ScrollView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size classes are for categories of devices, not individual devices themselves. This means that you can't design specifically for 3.5-inch screens by using a size class.

You will have to use something like the following to check if your app is running on a 3.5-inch screen:

```
#define IS_IPHONE_4  ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )480 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

...and then update the position of your desired view - either by settings its frame or updating its constraints.

Comment: Thanks, i know that way. But is there no smooth and nice way to do it in storyboard?!

Comment: @chrizstone Not as far as I know - but someone else is welcome to chime in if they have an answer! The closest thing would be size classes, but they aren't able to target specific screen sizes.